# Email alerts on Sharepoint not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

when configuring the 'Alert Me' option in library I'm receiving an error that states "You do not have an address. Alert has been created successfully but you will not receive notifications until valid e-mail or mobile address has been provided in your profile".

The email field is set in AD so I'm not sure why this is happening, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured user profile synchronization?

Here are similar threads for your reference.

https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/error-alert-has-been-created-successfully-but-you-will-not-receive-notifications-until-valid-e-mail-or-mobile-address-has-been-provided-in-your-profile/

http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.sg/2013/06/alert-error-you-do-not-have-e-mail.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for you to troubleshoot alerts function in SharePoint:

[SharePoint Troubleshooting: Alert Email Does Not Go Out](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.troubleshooting-steps-for-sharepoint-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx)